# SQLAlchemy how to escape a bind parameter inside of text()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I escape a `:` inside of a string passed to `text()` to prevent SQLAlchemy from treating it like a bindparameter?

```
conn.execute(text("select 'My favorite emoticon is :p' from dual")).fetchone()
```

Will result in:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'p'
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/cd3x)
```

'

It's a bit confusing because from the context of selecting a string from the database `select 'foo :bar baz'` a bindparameter doesn't make much sense here.

It looks like I can use a `\` to escape this, but it says it is deprecated:

```
>>> conn.execute(text("select 'My favorite emoticon is \:p' from dual")).fetchone()
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \:
('My favorite emoticon is :p',)
```

Comment: How attached are you to using `text()`? This would be moot with more conventional query-builder usage (and accordingly, it might not hurt to mention that you're using `text()` in the title).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In this particular case I need to execute raw sql. It is actually being used to create PLSQL code. I've edited the title.

Comment: Two questions: **(1)** `from dual` suggests that you are using Oracle. If so, please [edit] or tag your question to let us know that. **(2)** What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.15. While I am running into this error on Oracle, I don't think that is the root cause. SQLalchemy is rather scanning the text and assuming I am entering a bindparam when I am not. I think you could replicate this on postgres or mysql with `conn.execute(text("select 'foo :bar baz")).fetchone()`

Comment: re: *"I think you could replicate this …"* - FWIW, I can't reproduce it with mssql. [This code](https://pastebin.com/zD2FXF0s) works fine for me.

Comment: @GordThompson I was able to replicate it on postgres. I don't have mssql installed. I actually had a spelling error in my previous comment; can you try copy and pasting the following: `conn.execute(text("select 'foo :bar baz'")).fetchone()` Please note the inclusion of the single `'`s.

Comment: Yes, `conn.execute(text("select 'foo :bar baz'")).fetchone()` fails because the colon is not escaped with a backslash. However, `conn.execute(text("select 'foo \\:bar baz'")).fetchone()` works, as does `conn.execute(text(r"select 'foo \:bar baz'")).fetchone()`

Comment: @GordThompson Both of these two remove the deprecation warning. Thanks. Would you like to post as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text):

> For SQL statements where a colon is required verbatim, as within an inline string, use a backslash to escape

But remember that the backslash is also the escape character in Python string literals, so

```py
text("select 'My favorite emoticon is \:p' from dual")
```

is incorrect because Python will want to interpret `\:` as an escape character. We need to use either a "raw string" (`r""`)

```py
text(r"select 'My favorite emoticon is \:p' from dual")
```

or escape the backslash itself

```py
text("select 'My favorite emoticon is \\:p' from dual")
```